# Why can't I restore into a newly created database?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a backup of my database using the following commands:

`pg_dump -Fc mydatabase > db.dump`

I can restore this backup using the `pg_restore -C` by first creating the database outlined in the backup file and then connecting to it. However, when I try to restore the backup with `pg_restore` without the `-C` into a newly created database nothing happens. I run the following command:

`pg_restore -d newdatabase`

When I attempt to view all columns of `newdatabase` I get:

`ERROR:  relation "newdatabase" does not exist`

I am essentially doing what the documentation told me:

[image]

Any help as to why this is happening or how to restore into a newly created database using `pg_restore`would be great.

EDIT:

I just checked if `newdatabase` exists and it does:

[image]

Comment: Probably a database does not exist?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: `pg_restore -d newdatabase db.dump` I use this code to restore db.dump to `newdatabase` @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Also: "*When I attempt to view all columns of newdatabase*"  doesn't make sense. A database has not columns. A database contains schemas. A schema contains tables. And a **table** has columns. What is the command that generates "*ERROR:  relation "newdatabase" does not exist*"

Comment: `SELECT * FROM newdatabase;` @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: You don't select from a database, you select from a **table** that's _in_ the database.